# How to work with multiple tables (CRUD project) .Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 classes and I already created the ViewModel but idk how to work with it, I have to create a CRUD using these 2 classes. How to create the methods to **UPDATE** and **DELETE**? (i already done the create method)

(I'm using .Net Mvc, MySql Database and EF)

The classes:

Fornecedor

```cs
[Key]
public int IdFornec { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "char")]
[Required]
[StringLength(14)]
public string CNPJ { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string NomeFornec { get; set; }

public int? IdEndFornec { get; set; }

public virtual endereco endereco { get; set; }
```

Endereco

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
public endereco()
{
    cliente = new HashSet<cliente>();
    fornecedor = new HashSet<fornecedor>();
}

[Key]
public int IdEnd { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "char")]
[StringLength(8)]
public string CEP { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(150)]
public string Logradouro { get; set; }

[StringLength(100)]
public string NomeBairro { get; set; }

[StringLength(80)]
public string NomeCidade { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(2)]
public string UF { get; set; }

[StringLength(150)]
public string CompEnd { get; set; }

public short? NumEnd { get; set; }

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<cliente> cliente { get; set; }

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<fornecedor> fornecedor { get; set; }
```

The ViewModel

```cs
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[MaxLength(14)]
public string CNPJ { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(100)]
public string NomeFornec { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "char")]
[MaxLength(8)]
public string CEP { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(150)]
public string Logradouro { get; set; }

[MaxLength(100)]
public string NomeBairro { get; set; }

[MaxLength(80)]
public string NomeCidade { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(2)]
public string UF { get; set; }

[MaxLength(150)]
public string CompEnd { get; set; }

public short? NumEnd { get; set; }
```

Comment: You should start from reading this tutorial: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net

Comment: I spent a lot of time reading this, but I still don't know how to make updates to multiple tables, can u be more specific?

Comment: Which version of EF do you use? Usually if you want to update some entity, you just query for it, then update properties, then call for SaveChanges(). If entity has "sub entities", you need to inlcude them using "Include" method when constructing query. I am talking about EF Core.